# Significantly different time of execution of the query due to different date value in Postgres

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I have a weird case of query execution performance here. The query has a date values in the `WHERE` clause, and the speed of executing varies by values of the date.

Actually:

- for the dates from the range of the last 30 days, execution takes around **3 min**
- for the dates before the range of the last 30 days, execution takes **a few seconds**

The query is listed below, with the date in the last 30 days range:

```
select 
    sk2_.code as col_0_0_, 
    bra4_.code as col_1_0_, 
    st0_.quantity as col_2_0_, 
    bat1_.forecast as col_3_0_ 
from 
    TBL_st st0_, 
    TBL_bat bat1_, 
    TBL_sk sk2_, 
    TBL_bra bra4_ 
where 
    st0_.batc_id=bat1_.id 
    and bat1_.sku_id=sk2_.id 
    and bat1_.bran_id=bra4_.id 
    and  not (exists (select 
        1 
    from 
        TBL_st st6_, 
        TBL_bat bat7_, 
        TBL_sk sk10_ 
    where 
        st6_.batc_id=bat7_.id 
        and bat7_.sku_id=sk10_.id 
        and bat7_.bran_id=bat1_.bran_id 
        and sk10_.code=sk2_.code 
        and st6_.date>st0_.date 
        and sk10_.acco_id=1 
        and st6_.date>='2017-04-20' 
        and st6_.date<='2017-04-30')) 
    and sk2_.acco_id=1 
    and st0_.date>='2017-04-20' 
    and st0_.date<='2017-04-30'
```

and here is the plan for the query with the date in the last  30 days range:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=289.06..19764.03 rows=1 width=430) (actual time=3482.062..326049.246 rows=249 loops=1) 
  ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=288.91..19763.86 rows=1 width=433) (actual time=3482.023..326048.023 rows=249 loops=1) 
        Join Filter: ((st6_.date > st0_.date) AND ((sk10_.code)::text = (sk2_.code)::text)) 
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 210558 
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=286.43..13719.38 rows=1 width=441) (actual time=4.648..2212.042 rows=2474 loops=1) 
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=286.00..6871.33 rows=13335 width=436) (actual time=4.262..657.823 rows=666738 loops=1) 
                    ->  Index Scan using uk_TBL_sk0_account_code on TBL_sk sk2_  (cost=0.14..12.53 rows=1 width=426) (actual time=1.036..1.084 rows=50 loops=1) 
                          Index Cond: (acco_id = 1) 
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on TBL_bat bat1_  (cost=285.86..6707.27 rows=15153 width=26) (actual time=3.675..11.308 rows=13335 loops=50) 
                          Recheck Cond: (sku_id = sk2_.id) 
                          Heap Blocks: exact=241295 
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_al_batc_sku_id  (cost=0.00..282.07 rows=15153 width=0) (actual time=3.026..3.026 rows=13335 loops=50) 
                                Index Cond: (sku_id = sk2_.id) 
              ->  Index Scan using ix_al_stle_batc_id on TBL_st st0_  (cost=0.42..0.50 rows=1 width=21) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=666738) 
                    Index Cond: (batc_id = bat1_.id) 
                    Filter: ((date >= '2017-04-20 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date <= '2017-04-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)) 
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1 
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.49..3023.47 rows=1 width=434) (actual time=111.345..130.883 rows=86 loops=2474) 
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.06..2045.18 rows=1905 width=434) (actual time=0.010..28.028 rows=54853 loops=2474) 
                    Hash Cond: (bat7_.sku_id = sk10_.id) 
                    ->  Index Scan using ix_al_batc_bran_id on TBL_bat bat7_  (cost=0.42..1667.31 rows=95248 width=24) (actual time=0.009..11.045 rows=54853 loops=2474) 
                          Index Cond: (bran_id = bat1_.bran_id) 
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.63..1.63 rows=1 width=426) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=50 loops=1) 
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB 
                          ->  Seq Scan on TBL_sk sk10_  (cost=0.00..1.63 rows=1 width=426) (actual time=0.007..0.015 rows=50 loops=1) 
                                Filter: (acco_id = 1) 
              ->  Index Scan using ix_al_stle_batc_id on TBL_st st6_  (cost=0.42..0.50 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=135706217) 
                    Index Cond: (batc_id = bat7_.id) 
                    Filter: ((date >= '2017-04-20 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date <= '2017-04-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)) 
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1 
  ->  Index Scan using TBL_bra_pk on TBL_bra bra4_  (cost=0.14..0.16 rows=1 width=13) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=249) 
        Index Cond: (id = bat1_.bran_id) 
Planning time: 8.108 ms 
Execution time: 326049.583 ms
```

Here is the same query with the date before the last 30 days range:

```
select 
    sk2_.code as col_0_0_, 
    bra4_.code as col_1_0_, 
    st0_.quantity as col_2_0_, 
    bat1_.forecast as col_3_0_ 
from 
    TBL_st st0_, 
    TBL_bat bat1_, 
    TBL_sk sk2_, 
    TBL_bra bra4_ 
where 
    st0_.batc_id=bat1_.id 
    and bat1_.sku_id=sk2_.id 
    and bat1_.bran_id=bra4_.id 
    and  not (exists (select 
        1 
    from 
        TBL_st st6_, 
        TBL_bat bat7_, 
        TBL_sk sk10_ 
    where 
        st6_.batc_id=bat7_.id 
        and bat7_.sku_id=sk10_.id 
        and bat7_.bran_id=bat1_.bran_id 
        and sk10_.code=sk2_.code 
        and st6_.date>st0_.date 
        and sk10_.acco_id=1 
        and st6_.date>='2017-01-20' 
        and st6_.date<='2017-01-30')) 
    and sk2_.acco_id=1 
    and st0_.date>='2017-01-20' 
    and st0_.date<='2017-01-30'
```

and here is the plan for the query with the date before the last  30 days range:

```
  Hash Join  (cost=576.33..27443.95 rows=48 width=430) (actual time=132.732..3894.554 rows=250 loops=1) 
  Hash Cond: (bat1_.bran_id = bra4_.id) 
  ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=572.85..27439.82 rows=48 width=433) (actual time=132.679..3894.287 rows=250 loops=1) 
        Merge Cond: ((sk2_.code)::text = (sk10_.code)::text) 
        Join Filter: ((st6_.date > st0_.date) AND (bat7_.bran_id = bat1_.bran_id)) 
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 84521 
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=286.43..13719.38 rows=48 width=441) (actual time=26.105..1893.523 rows=2491 loops=1) 
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=286.00..6871.33 rows=13335 width=436) (actual time=1.159..445.683 rows=666738 loops=1) 
                    ->  Index Scan using uk_TBL_sk0_account_code on TBL_sk sk2_  (cost=0.14..12.53 rows=1 width=426) (actual time=0.035..0.084 rows=50 loops=1) 
                          Index Cond: (acco_id = 1) 
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on TBL_bat bat1_  (cost=285.86..6707.27 rows=15153 width=26) (actual time=1.741..7.148 rows=13335 loops=50) 
                          Recheck Cond: (sku_id = sk2_.id) 
                          Heap Blocks: exact=241295 
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_al_batc_sku_id  (cost=0.00..282.07 rows=15153 width=0) (actual time=1.119..1.119 rows=13335 loops=50) 
                                Index Cond: (sku_id = sk2_.id) 
              ->  Index Scan using ix_al_stle_batc_id on TBL_st st0_  (cost=0.42..0.50 rows=1 width=21) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=666738) 
                    Index Cond: (batc_id = bat1_.id) 
                    Filter: ((date >= '2017-01-20 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date <= '2017-01-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)) 
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1 
        ->  Materialize  (cost=286.43..13719.50 rows=48 width=434) (actual time=15.584..1986.953 rows=84560 loops=1) 
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=286.43..13719.38 rows=48 width=434) (actual time=15.577..1983.384 rows=2491 loops=1) 
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=286.00..6871.33 rows=13335 width=434) (actual time=0.843..482.864 rows=666738 loops=1) 
                          ->  Index Scan using uk_TBL_sk0_account_code on TBL_sk sk10_  (cost=0.14..12.53 rows=1 width=426) (actual time=0.005..0.052 rows=50 loops=1) 
                                Index Cond: (acco_id = 1) 
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on TBL_bat bat7_  (cost=285.86..6707.27 rows=15153 width=24) (actual time=2.051..7.902 rows=13335 loops=50) 
                                Recheck Cond: (sku_id = sk10_.id) 
                                Heap Blocks: exact=241295 
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_al_batc_sku_id  (cost=0.00..282.07 rows=15153 width=0) (actual time=1.424..1.424 rows=13335 loops=50) 
                                      Index Cond: (sku_id = sk10_.id) 
                    ->  Index Scan using ix_al_stle_batc_id on TBL_st st6_  (cost=0.42..0.50 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=666738) 
                          Index Cond: (batc_id = bat7_.id) 
                          Filter: ((date >= '2017-01-20 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date <= '2017-01-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)) 
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 1 
  ->  Hash  (cost=2.10..2.10 rows=110 width=13) (actual time=0.033..0.033 rows=110 loops=1) 
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 14kB 
        ->  Seq Scan on TBL_bra bra4_  (cost=0.00..2.10 rows=110 width=13) (actual time=0.004..0.013 rows=110 loops=1) 
Planning time: 14.542 ms 
Execution time: 3894.793 ms
```

Does anyone have an idea why does this happens.

Did anyone had an experience with anything similar?

Thank you very much. 
Kind regards, Petar

Comment: what postgresql version are you using?

Comment: Is there any good reason *not* to use JOIN-syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I had a similar case a while ago(On ORACLE but i guess it is not important).

in my case the difference originated at the difference between the amount of data, meaning: if you have 1% of data from the past 30 days, it uses the indexs. when you need "older" data (the rest 99% of the data) it decides to not use the index and to do a full scan(in the form of nested loop and not hash join).

If you sure that the data distribution is ok then maybe try collecting statistics(worked for me at the time). eventually you can start to analyze every peace of this query and to see what part exactly is the bottleneck and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

BTree indexes can have some issues with dates, especially if you're removing old data from the table (ie, deleting everything older than 90 days).  It can cause the tables to get lopsided, with all of the rows being down one branch of the tree.  Even without removing old dates, if there are many more "new" rows than "old" rows, it can still happen.

But I don't see your query plans using an index on st0_.date, so I don't think that's the issue.  If you can afford a table lock on st0_, you can test this theory by running a REINDEX operation on any indexes that contain st0_.date.

Instead, I think you just have a lot more rows that match the 2017-01-20 to 2017-01-30 range vs. the 2017-04-20 to 2017-04-30 range.  The first doubly indented Nested Loop is the same in both queries, so I'll ignore it.  The second doubly indended stanza is different, and much more expensive in the slow query:

```
->  Materialize  (cost=286.43..13719.50 rows=48 width=434) (actual time=15.584..1986.953 rows=84560 loops=1)
      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=286.43..13719.38 rows=48 width=434) (actual time=15.577..1983.384 rows=2491 loops=1)
            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=286.00..6871.33 rows=13335 width=434) (actual time=0.843..482.864 rows=666738
```

vs

```
->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.49..3023.47 rows=1 width=434) (actual time=111.345..130.883 rows=86 loops=2474)
      ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.06..2045.18 rows=1905 width=434) (actual time=0.010..28.028 rows=54853 loops=2474)
```

Materialize can be an expensive operation that doesn't necessarily scale with the estimated cost.  Take a look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/using-explain.html , and search for "Materialize".  Also note that the estimated number of rows is much higher in the slow version.

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that tweaking the "work_mem" parameter can have some effect in this area (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM).  To test this theory, you can change that value per session using

```
SET LOCAL work_mem = '8MB';
```